# An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services when doing migrations and customisingasp.net user and roles tables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services when doing migrations and customisingasp.net user and roles tables

I am using .Net 6 and I am trying to customise the roles tables so that it caters for some extra columns
The project builds however when I try to add an initial migrationI get an erorr

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> GenericArguments[0], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser', on
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]'
> violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

I think were I am going wrong is the ApplicationDbContext base class and  the way I am ordering  all the generic parameters

**Custom user class with extra fields**

```
namespace AngularAuthAPI.Models.Authentication
{
    public class UserInformation: IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public int CenterID { get; set; }
            /*public int UserName { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
            public string ContactDetails { get; set; }*/
            
        public int NumberOfCandidates { get; set; }
        public bool Approved { get; set; }
        public bool TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public int CenterType { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsSchoolAdmin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Custom role class with extra fields**

```
namespace AngularAuthAPI.Models.Authentication
{
    public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole<Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationRole() : base()
        { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name)
        { }
        public string? RoleDescription { get; set; }
        public string? RoleName { get; set; }
        
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public int CenterID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext with role**

```
namespace AngularAuthAPI.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserInformation,  ApplicationRole, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            {

            }
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
        
        /*private void SeedRoles (ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasData
            (
               new IdentityRole() { Name = "Invigilator", ConcurrencyStamp = "1", NormalizedName = "Invigilator" },
                new IdentityRole() { Name = "Student", ConcurrencyStamp = "2", NormalizedName = "Student" },
               new IdentityRole() { Name = "SuperAdmin", ConcurrencyStamp = "3", NormalizedName = "SuperAdmin" }
            ); 
       }*/
    }

}
```

**Program.cs to register services**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); 

    builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Adding Authentication
```

Comment: From your question, you custom `IdentityUser` via `UserInformation` model, But why you just use `IdentityUser` in `builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, ApplicationRole>()` instead of `UserInformation` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you custom `IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole` class and Change the primary key type, So here you need to add Identity in `Program.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<UserInformation, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now Database can be created successfully

[image]

You can also refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to learn more.

Comment: Hi @Zidane, Can this answer solved your issue?

Comment: Thank you @Xinran Shen. Could you let me know what's the namespace of `AddDefaultUI()` ? It does not  resolved in my code.